# Can an algorithm run in "O(n/a)" time?

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics

**On one hand,** it seems to make no sense, because of the following:

When expanded, the claim $f(n,a) \in O(n/a)$ would be

> There exist $C > 0$, $n_0$, and $a_0$ such that if $n \geq n_0$ and $a \geq a_0$, then $f(n,a) \leq C \cdot n/a$.

Now, given any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find an $a_\epsilon \geq a_0$ such that 
$C \cdot n_0/a_\epsilon < \epsilon$, and thus $f(n_0, a_\epsilon) < \epsilon$.

So for any $\epsilon$, there is an input, with $n = n_0$ and $a = a_\epsilon$, at which the algorithm takes less than $\epsilon$ time to run. 
But any nontrivial algorithm performs at least one operation, regardless of the input. So this seems nonsensical.

**On the other hand,** you can imagine someone saying that some approximation algorithm runs in time "$O(n/a)$", where $n$ is the size of the input and $a$ is the maximum multiplicative error.

And in fact, there is a paper in which an algorithm is claimed to run in "$\tilde{O}(\frac{n}{A^3 \epsilon})$" time. (Yes, I know $\tilde{O}$ is different from $O$). I asked a longer question about that
[here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/94043/big-o-tildeo-notation-with-multiple-variables-when-function-is-decreasin). This question is an attempt to isolate the core confusion there.

Answer (score 4):

For approximation algorithms, the algorithm must return an answer within a factor of $1\pm\epsilon$ of the true value. As such, smaller values of $\epsilon$ correspond to better approximations. As such, a running time that's polynomial in $n$ and $1/\epsilon$ is what you'd intuitively look for: it's saying that a better approximation (smaller $\epsilon$, so larger $1/\epsilon$) will take more time, but not by an unerasonable amount.

Also, note that we typically have an upper bound on $\epsilon$. For example, suppose we want to approximately compute the distance between two distinct vertices in a connected graph. We know the distance must be between $1$ and $n$ the number of vertices) so if we just want an approximation within $1\pm\epsilon$ and $\epsilon\ge\sqrt{n}$, we can just return $\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 4):

The interpretation is closer to the following:

> There exists $C>0$ such that for all $n,a$, $f(n,a) \leq C(n/a)$.

But this is also not quite right, since not all values of $n,a$ make sense.

Taking a look at the [actual paper](http://www.eng.tau.ac.il/~danar/Public-pdf/comp.pdf), we see that Algorithm IV calls Algorithm V with the parameter $B = A/2\sqrt{\log(2/A\epsilon)}$.

Algorithm V, in turn, tacitly assumes that $B^2 \leq n$ (note that confusingly enough, they use $A$ instead of $B$ for the approximation parameter). This means that $A$ is constrained to satisfy
$$
\frac{A}{2\sqrt{\log(2/A\epsilon)}} \leq \sqrt{n}.
$$

The running time of Algorithm IV is stated in full in Lemma 6:
$$ O\left(\frac{n}{A^3 \epsilon} \log^2 \frac{1}{A\epsilon}\right). $$
This means that there exists a constant $C$ such that the running time is at most
$$ C\frac{n}{A^3 \epsilon} \log^2 \frac{1}{A\epsilon}, $$
for all $A,\epsilon,n$ satisfying
$$
\frac{A}{2\sqrt{\log(2/A\epsilon)}} \leq \sqrt{n}.
$$
(There might be additional constraints that I missed.)

This is the meaning of $\tilde{O}(\frac{n}{A^3\epsilon})$ for Algorithm IV.

Comment: This is helpful, I didn't realize that the constraints on the parameters would enter into it. (There are indeed additional constraints, for example $2/(A\epsilon)$ must be greater than $1$ so that the argument to the square root is positive.) I know how to proceed now.