# Why $2R\sigma\sqrt{T+logT+1}=\tilde{{O}}(\sigma\sqrt{T})$?

Tags: asymptotics

On page 17 on the paper [Online Learning with Predictable Sequences](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.3728.pdf), we find a regret of an algorithm equal to

$$
\text{Reg}_T=\frac{R^2}{\eta}+\frac{\eta}{2}\sigma^2(T+logT+1)
$$
where $T$ is the entire time, $\eta$ is learning rate, $R$ is constant, and $\sigma^2$ is the variance of data. The above using arithmetic mean-geometric mean inequality can be lower bounded by

$$
\sqrt{2}R\sigma\sqrt{T+logT+1}\leq \frac{R^2}{\eta}+\frac{\eta}{2}\sigma^2(T+logT+1)
$$

why the left hand side is $\tilde{{O}}(\sigma\sqrt{T})$?

According to [$\tilde{{O}}$ vs $O$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744718/what-does-%C3%95-omicron-tilde-mean-in-complexity-%C3%95n-vs-on), $\tilde{{O}}$ ignores logarithmic factors that means when $f(n) \in \tilde{O}(g(n))$ there exist a $k$ such that $f(n) \in O(g(n)\log^k g(n))$, now I have $f(T)=\sqrt{2}R\sigma\sqrt{T+logT+1}$, why I can write it $O(\sigma\sqrt{T}log^kT)=\tilde{O}(\sigma\sqrt{T})$? and what is my $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is $\tilde O$? There are two different definitions.

- According to exercise 3.5 of *Introduction to Algorightms* by Corman et al., $\tilde O$ can mean $O$ with logarithmic factors ignored: $$\tilde O(g(n))= \{f(n): \text{there exist nonnegative constant } k \\ \text{ and positive constants } c, k, \text{ and }n_0
  \text{ such that }\\ 0\le f(n)\le cg(n)(\log n)^k\text{ for all }n\ge n_0\}$$
- According to [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Extensions_to_the_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations), $f(n) = \tilde O(g(n))$ is shorthand for $f(n) = O(g(n)\left(\log g(n)\right)^k)$ for some $k$.

For any value $x>0$, $x^0=1$. If we take $k=0$ simply, we can see that for either definition,
$$f(T)=\sqrt{2}R\sigma\sqrt{T+\log T+1}=O(\sigma \sqrt{T}) =O(\sigma \sqrt{T}\,1)=\tilde{O}(\sigma\sqrt{T})$$

---

Here is the explanation for the second equality in the above equation.

$\log T=o(T) \Rightarrow
T+\log T+1=\Theta(T) \Rightarrow \sqrt{T+\log T+1}=\Theta(\sqrt T)$

W can also proceed more rigorously, using L'Hôpital's rule once.

$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{T+\log T+1}}{\sqrt T} = \sqrt{\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{T+\log T+1}{T}} = \sqrt{\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac1T}{1}}=1$$

Comment: my question is why $\tilde{\mathcal{O}}$ not $\mathcal{O}$ ? Could you address that?

Comment: I revised the statement to elaborate my question clearly, please take a look.

Comment: $\textbf{Wikipedia entry:}$ This notation is often used to obviate the "nitpicking" within growth-rates that are stated as too tightly bounded for the matters at hand (since $n\log k$ is always $o(n\epsilon)$ for any constant k and any $\epsilon > 0$).

Comment: @Sagnik: I understand that. What I do not understand is why $O(T+\log T)=O(T\log T)$?

Comment: @Saeed When $T> 10$, $T\log T - (T+\log T) = (T-1)(\log T -1) + 1 > 0$, i.e. $T+\log T<T\log T$. So any function that grows asymptotically slower than $T+\log T$ modulo a constant factor also grows asymptotically slower than $T\log T$ modulo a constant factor, i.e., $O(T+\log T)=O(T\log T)$

Comment: @Apass.Jack : The last $1$ in the r.h.s of the equality should be $-1$. It works for $t \geq 4$.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that in my other post as well.

Comment: @Apass.Jack: The last line it should be $O(\sigma \sqrt{T+\log T})=O(\sigma \sqrt{T\log T})=\tilde{O}(\sigma \sqrt{T})$

Comment: As I have proved in [the previous version of this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/102078/1), $\sqrt{T+logT+1}=\Theta(\sqrt T)$. So $O(\sigma \sqrt{T+\log T})=O(\sigma \sqrt{T})$

Comment: @Apass.Jack : But it is not in your answer anymore. You have revised your answer, and I want the accepted answer stands alone.

Comment: Good point. I just brought back that part.